# How to export and verify a signed gpg public key?

Tags: gpg

I signed the public key of `bob@example.com` with 3 of my identities. 
I did **not use** `lsign` so that the signature is exportable.
The signatures are listed properly with

```
gpg --list-signatures bob@example.com
```

Now I want to send bob a mail including his key with my signature so that
he can decide to upload it to his favorite key server, or not.

I tried to prepare the attachment

```
gpg --armor --export bob@example.com > bob.asc
```

I want to verify, that the file includes my signatures, but I can not see my signatures with

```
gpg --with-colons bob.asc
```

**a) How do I properly export bob's key with my signatures to a file?**

**b) How can I verify the file afterwards?**

Answer (score 1):

```
# assuming gnupg-tmp is empty or non-existing
mkdir -p gnupg-tmp
gpg --homedir gnupg-tmp/ --import bob.asc your_key.asc
gpg --homedir gnupg-tmp/ --edit-key bob@example.com
clean
save
gpg --homedir gnupg-tmp/ --list-sigs bob@example.com
```

Importing the signing key and running `--edit-key clen` are not strictly necessary. Importing the key both makes the output more readable (but, of course, you could recognize or `grep` for your key ID, too) and allows `clean` to check your signature and removing all others.

You could use `--list-packets` directly on the exported file (i.e. without `--homedir`) but that may be confusing due to the number of signatures and the printed data and would not check the signatures.

Comment: Thank you. Could you add some more explanation, please? Why do I have to import `your_key.asc`? Is it correct, that this method will create a minimal copy of a keyring in order to keep the output of `--list-sigs` tidy?

Comment: @JonasStein Correct, that's what is does, among other things.

Comment: I could not see my signatures on bob's key. Does `--armor --export` not export the the signatures together with the public key?

Comment: @JonasStein `--export` ignores signatures which have been made with `lsign`.